# Configure Swagger on AspNet Core Identity Server4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, identityserver4, openapi

We have been trying to achieve configuring Swagger on Aspnet Core Identity  Server 4 Application,
we have added Custom End points to ID4 refered from [link](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html).

**Swagger Configuration:**

Code added on Startup.cs > ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Identity Server Application", Version = "v1" });
        });
```

Code added on  Startup.cs > Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)

```
      // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Identity Server Application");
        });
```

When i run application swagger/index.html only showing Custom Added End Points,its not showing Identity  Server Endpoints like {connect/authorize,connect/token,connect/userinfo etc.}

Can any one please give me right direction to achieve above functionality.